# Fine Uploader need to chunk a file and rejoin back

Tags: php, file-upload, fine-uploader

I am trying to integrate **fine uploader [ Jquery wrapper ]** for my PHP project. In that, i am trying to upload a 25MB file by using chunking option.

But what is happening here is, It chunks file and stores as **blob0, blob1, blob2...**

I want to my original file to be stored in the location. But here, the chunks get stored with a different name. What i have tired so far is,

```
<div id="jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader"></div>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.fineuploader-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
            debug: true, 
            request: {
                endpoint: 'upload.php',
            },

            chunking: {
                enabled: true,
                partSize: 2000000, 
                paramNames: {
                    partIndex: 'qqpartindex',
                    partByteOffset: 'qqpartbyteoffset',
                    chunkSize: 'qqchunksize',
                    totalFileSize: 'qqtotalfilesize',
                    totalParts: 'qqtotalparts',
                    filename: 'qqfile'
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
if ($_FILES["qqfile"]["error"] > 0)
{
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["qqfile"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
    $partIndex  =   $_POST["qqpartindex"];
    $fileName   =   $_POST["qqfile"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["qqfile"]["tmp_name"], "data/" . $_FILES["qqfile"]["name"].$partIndex);
    $result['success']  =   true;
    echo json_encode($result);

}
```

I don't know where i went wrong and what i have missed. Please someone guide me.

Comment: you can use this https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload its awesome and work perfect however hard to modify

Comment: Please keep bickering out of comments.

Comment: Also, there is no need to define the `paramNames` property if you are going to simply use the default values.

Comment: @RayNicholus I tried that example and it is working fine. Thank you so much

Comment: @EdwinAlex You're quite welcome.  If you have any further questions/problems with Fine Uploader, feel free to open up a case here.  I'm usually the one to answer them.  I also maintain the library.

Comment: Edwin (deleted and re-created my earlier comment as the link was wrong) - There is a very comprehensive [PHP example](http://bit.ly/10bAetm) that covers chunking and auto resume in the server directory of the Fine Uploader Github project. Many other users are currently using it, in fact. You should use that as a reference as it is fully functional and it should answer all of your questions regarding your attempt to integrate Fine Uploader with your server-side environment via PHP. If you have any specific problems with this example, please comment here or open up a new case here on SO.

Comment: Try [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/documentation.php) - it provides an option to upload a file in various chunks and upload them in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

The point is, this is a feature of the fine uploader.  The chunks are given as separate files so that in case your upload gets corrupted, you would have a way to compare and discard chunks that are invalid.  If you wish to just get the file, what you need is the following:

```
if ($_FILES["qqfile"]["error"] > 0)
{
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["qqfile"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
    $partIndex  =   $_POST["qqpartindex"];
    $fileName   =   $_POST["qqfile"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["qqfile"]["tmp_name"], "data/" . $_FILES["qqfile"]["name"].$partIndex);
    // INSERT CODE HERE TO CHECK THE INTEGRITY OF "data/" . $_FILES["qqfile"]["name"].$partIndex
    $file = fopen($filename, 'a');
    $content = file_get_contents("data/" . $_FILES["qqfile"]["name"].$partIndex);
    if (fwrite($file, $content)) $result['success'] = true;
    fclose($file);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

, where $filename is the name of the file you are uploading.  I would tell you how to get it through this code, but it's probably easier to define it upstream.  Also, depending on your upstream code, it will probably be more memory-efficient to do the fopen at the beginning of the upload, and fclose at the end of your code (e.g.

```
$file = FALSE;
if ($partIndex == 0) $file = fopen("filename");
```

instead of the line $file = fopen($filename, 'a');  But, in this case you need to fclose($file); only at the end of the upload (or not at all, it will be fclosed once the page loads).  But once again, without seeing the rest of your code I cannot know what will work best in this particular case.